# How to provide completion for tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

By default in the tasks.json, there is a completion for:[image]

which is creating:

```
{
    "label": "My Task",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "echo Hello",
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

How can I add my own task examples as completion?

Comment: You could register a `CompletionItemProvider` for JSON files and check that the file name is `tasks.json`.

Comment: thanks, I followed this direction https://github.com/camel-tooling/vscode-camelk/pull/312
I was hoping to have something a bit more convenient for tasks.json as there are specific contribution points. But maybe not. The CompletionItemprovider does the trick.